# Offset plot price crossing plot price in Pine Script

Tags: plot, offset, pine-script

Let's say I want to make a new label/signal when Price and -Offset Price are crossing each other

```
abc = plot(close, color=color.aqua)
xyz = plot(close, offset=-25, color=color.lime)

condA = crossover(abc, xyz)
condB = crossunder(abc, xyz)
```

Since you can't get `cross` function work if using `plot` as `x and y` and also `offset` function value can't be a negative

It's from Ichimoku Cloud, I want to get add a condition when Lagging Span and Price value are crossing each other

What is the right command to get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lagging span is just the current close offset into the past. So you can just compare close values that take into account the offset.

`condA = crossover(close, close[offset])`